# best optimal regular expression to extract Version number from file name

Tags: regex, jar, version

Could anyone please advice best optimal regular expression to extract Version number from file names. Files of any type like JAR or any other type.

As individual teams are using there own ways to have version number like some added at start, some at end, some at middle, some with more info with version number etc. etc.

So, looking for a best optimal regular expression to get version number from file names.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per my findings, below regular expression is the optimal solution: -

To get version name from filename (filename without extension), if the version number is anywhere in file name except at starting: -

```
  ([_-]\d+(?:[.\-_]\w*\d+)+)
```

Below are few filenames having different-different varieties of version number and using above Regular Expression, able to extract version number successfully.: -

[image: Image Showing Different Version combinations (not at start) captured using mentioned Regular Expression]
*Snap is captured from https://regex101.com/*

And if the version number is at start of filename then same regex as above only

- Adding ^ to get matches that are at start of a string and
- Removed the single hyphen/underscore matching from start of version number --> [_-]

```
  ^(\d+(?:[.\-_]\w*\d+)+)
```

[image: Image Showing Different Version combinations written at start of file name and captured using above mentioned Regular Expression]